# How do I run the VS code IDE for C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I get the error:

> Failed to create "c:'Program Files': EPERM:operation not permitted,''
>   mkdir 'c:'Program Files', 'Microsoft VS Code'.

When I try to write some code in C when I start `#include <stdio.h>` in VS code and noc what to do

I've tried to move him to the PATH but I don't know if that's where the thing goes.

Comment: Are you running it on Windows or a Unix-like platform?  Were there any backslashes in the messages?

Comment: I try in windows

Comment: download the gcc compiler